# Cannot get a specific letter in a string of a command

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, discord, discord.py

I have been having trouble getting a specific part of the command. What I intend to do is that when L is in the x position I want it to send a message that is formatted one way and when L is in a different position I want it to send a different message.

The command I am working with here is:
!en L BTC 19500
Nothing prints in the embed when I run the code

```
@bot.command() 
    async def en(ctx):
            if (ctx.author.id == 573284477158162433 or 244240895627624448):
                global channels, message
                x = ctx.message.content
                
                print(len(x))
                if(x[4:len(x)-11]=="L"):
                    message = "**Type:Long **"+"**Ticker: **"+x[4:len(x)-6] + "\n  **Entry Price:** " + x[7:]
                print(message)
        
             
                f=0
                for i in range(len(channels)):
                 f+=1
                 current_server = channels[i]
                 disc_channel = bot.get_channel(current_server)
               
                await ctx.send(content = "@everyone", allowed_mentions = allowed_mentions)
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Entry", description=message, color=0x70f508)
                embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                embed.set_footer(text="Viggy Analytics")
                await disc_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to check if the `ctx.author.id` is equal to both ids. The way you are doing it now only checks if it's equal to `573284477158162433`. Second, you need to include the code that sends the embed inside the for-loop if you want it to send to each of the channels in your `channels` list. Lastly, your string slice should be `x[4:len(x)-10]`, since `x[4:len(x)-11]` deletes the entire message content following the command. However, a much simpler way of doing this is simply getting `x[4]`. [Here's](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_slice.asp) a short tutorial on how to slice strings properly in Python.

```py
@bot.command()
async def en(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.id == 573284477158162433 or ctx.author.id == 244240895627624448):
        global channels, message
        x = ctx.message.content

        if (x[4] == "L"):
            message = "**Type:Long **" + "**Ticker: **" + x[4:len(x) - 6] + "\n  **Entry Price:** " + x[7:]
        print(message)

        f = 0
        for i in range(len(channels)):
            f += 1
            current_server = channels[i]
            disc_channel = bot.get_channel(current_server)

        await ctx.send(content="@everyone", allowed_mentions=allowed_mentions)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Entry", description=message, color=0x70f508)
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        embed.set_footer(text="Viggy Analytics")
        await disc_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response why wouldnt the second id work